# Currently what is the best Firewall & Internet security for Ubuntu?

Tags: firewall

Currently what is the best Firewall & Internet security for Ubuntu?

Comment: Questions about "the best" are generally just asking for opinions, which is not the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Firewall

Ubuntu has an inbuilt firewall caled `ufw`

The graphical version for it is `gufw`. Search in the Ubuntu Software Center you will find it

Ufw is installed by default and is one of the strongest firewalls ever

See this Ubuntu Documentation for Firewalls

- [Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html)

### Antivirus

Regarding an Antivirus software, you dont need one because linux rarely catches a virus.
There are hardly any linux viruses

If you insist on having one for windows files on linux,

Then install `Clamav` found in the Ubuntu Software Center and the gui frontend for it is `clamtk` also found in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Check these Ubuntu documentations for more info

- [Antivirus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)
- [Do I need anti-virus software?](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-antivirus.html)

Also see this

- [Top 5 Anti virus for ubuntu](http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.in/2011/10/top-5-anti-virus-for-ubuntu.html)

Comment: @Ali Glad to help. :)

Comment: Worst advice ever- old post to blame, but Linux gets hit by all sorts of things online in the year 2017.Application Firewalls is one way to go... especially with xss attacks, and linux does get hit by Trojans